# Use of reflexive pronouns

Tags: reflexive-pronouns

Is this the right sentence?

> Make it good for yourself.

"Yourself" is a reflexive pronoun; thus, it should be used only when there is a subject whose object is this pronoun. Like we can say:

Look at yourself.

The person who is seeing is seeing himslef.

so should this be:

Make it good for yourself.

OR

Make it good for you.

Make it common to you.

OR

Make it common among yourselves.

Answer (score 1):

> Make it good for yourself.

That is correct.

> Make it common among yourselves.

The grammar is correct but the usage of "make it common" is not idiomatic. I am not sure what it is supposed to mean. My guess is that it refers to some facts that are to be shared but I don't know.